# Why does my linked list not get printed? ( C language)

Tags: c, function, linked-list

I have written a code to enter the name, age, department id, company name, and salary respectively, of employees from a text file into a linked list. Right now, In my code, I have created an insert function and a display function. When I ran the code on the command prompt there were no errors found. However, my list did not get printed. Can someone help me out with this if possible? thankyou.

Here are the details of the file, it is called employee.txt:

```
Peter 30 1001 Apple 8000
Joseph 50 1002 Oracle 4000
Mary 40 1003 Samsung 6000
Lilly 40 1203 Samsung 7000
Tony 50 1002 Oracle 3000
Jake 30 1005 Apple 3000
Sam 40 1007 Samsung 4000
Lisa 30 1300 Oracle 5000
Kate 50 1200 Apple 6000
Rick 50 1313 Apple 4000
```

My Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct personTag {
    char name[20];
    int age;
};

struct officialTag {
    int deptId;
    char cmpName[20];
    double salary;
};

struct employeeTag {
    struct personTag personalInfo;
    struct officialTag officialInfo;
    struct employeeTag *next;
};

typedef struct employeeTag EmpTag;
typedef EmpTag *EmpTagPtr;

void insert(EmpTagPtr *s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid,
            char E_cmpname[], double E_salary);

void displayEmployees(EmpTagPtr s);

int main() {
    EmpTagPtr start = NULL;

    char E_name[20];
    int E_age;
    int E_deptid;
    char E_cmpname[20];
    double E_salary;

    // reading employee.txt file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("employee.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fp, "%s,%d,%d,%s,%lf", E_name, &E_age, &E_deptid, E_cmpname,
           &E_salary);

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        insert(&start, E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname,
               E_salary);  // inserting data to the new node
        fscanf(fp, "%s,%d,%d,%s,%lf", E_name, &E_age, &E_deptid, E_cmpname,
               &E_salary);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    displayEmployees(start);

    return 0;
}

void insert(EmpTagPtr *s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid,
            char E_cmpname[], double E_salary) {
    EmpTagPtr current = *s;
    EmpTagPtr prev = NULL;

    // create an empty node
    EmpTagPtr newNode;
    newNode = (EmpTag *)malloc(sizeof(EmpTag));

    // filling in the values
    strcpy(newNode->personalInfo.name, E_name);
    newNode->personalInfo.age = E_age;

    newNode->officialInfo.deptId = E_deptid;
    strcpy(newNode->officialInfo.cmpName, E_cmpname);
    newNode->officialInfo.salary = E_salary;

    newNode->next = NULL;

    while (current != NULL &&
           strcmp(current->personalInfo.name, prev->personalInfo.name) > 0) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (prev == NULL) {
        // add as the first node
        newNode->next = *s;
        *s = newNode;
    } else {
        prev->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = current;
    }
}

void displayEmployees(EmpTagPtr s) {
    EmpTagPtr current = s;

    while (current != NULL) {
        // printing the data part
        printf("Employee name:    %s\n", current->personalInfo.name);
        printf("Company name:     %s\n", current->officialInfo.cmpName);
        printf("Employee Age:     %d\n", current->personalInfo.age);
        printf("Department ID:    %d\n", current->officialInfo.deptId);
        printf("Employee Salary:  %lf\n", current->officialInfo.salary);
        printf("---------------------------------------------------------");
        current = current->next;  // move foward the current pointer
    }

    printf("NULL\n");
}
```

Comment: For me it segfaults in insert.

Comment: Was reading it and was just going to point this out. start == NULL. First time insert is called we are then access *s (that is *start) which is  NULL so you should get a NULL pointer access. On Windows this will simply look like the app runs and does nothing. You need to check s and make sure it is not NULL before you access it.

Comment: I fixed your data to remove the extra new lines.  Your fscanf comma separates fields but your data is space separated.  Which is it?

Comment: See [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2472827) Also, your file is not separated with commas, check the return value of `fscanf`.

Comment: That part is fine. start is basically a employeeTag**, so therefore *s is expected to get the first employeeTag*, however there is no first employeeTag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop to read uses the wrong `fscanf` format. The loop is also a bit overcomplicated. Just `fscanf` and check that you successfully extracted the `5` elements. Note the limits for the strings and removed commas:

```c
while (fscanf(fp, "%19s %d %d %19s %lf", E_name, &E_age, &E_deptid,
              E_cmpname, &E_salary) == 5)
{
    insert(&start, E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
}
```

The `insert` function has a buggy loop to find the insertion point. `prev` will be a `NULL` pointer here:

```c
while(current != NULL && strcmp(current->personalInfo.name,
      prev->personalInfo.name) >0 )
{
    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
}
```

Suggested fix:

```c
void insert(EmpTagPtr *s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid,
            char E_cmpname[], double E_salary) 
{
    // create an empty node
    EmpTagPtr newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);

    // filling in the values
    strcpy(newNode->personalInfo.name, E_name);
    newNode->personalInfo.age = E_age;

    newNode->officialInfo.deptId = E_deptid;
    strcpy(newNode->officialInfo.cmpName, E_cmpname);
    newNode->officialInfo.salary = E_salary;

    // use `newNode` in the comparison:
    while (*s && strcmp(newNode->personalInfo.name,
                        (*s)->personalInfo.name) > 0)
    {
        s = &(*s)->next;
    }

    // `s` now points at the `EmpTagPtr` pointer where the new node should
    // be inserted for the list to be sorted in alphabetical order.
    // If it's the first node to be inserted, `s` points at `start` so
    // you do not need `prev` or `current`:
    newNode->next = *s;
    *s = newNode;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3zhh5Gqnf)

As can be seen in the demo, your program leaks memory so you need to add a function to clean that up.

More about the insertion logic:

- Think of `start` as the `next` member of an imaginary first dummy node and `s` starts out pointing at `start`.
- If the linked list has zero elements, `start` will point at `NULL`.

  - `*s` will therefore be `== NULL` and the while loop will not do any laps.
  - You now assign `newNode->next = *s` (which is `NULL`) and assign `*s = newNode` (which means `start` will point at `newNode`). The first node is now completely linked.
- If the linked list has more than zero elements, the `while` loop will compare the name of the `newNode` with that of the dereferenced `s`'s name. `EmpTagPtr current = *s;` followed by `current->personalInfo.name` is the same as `(*s)->personalInfo.name`.

  - If `strcmp(newNode->personalInfo.name,  (*s)->personalInfo.name) > 0` we haven't found the insertion point and step `s` to point at the next node's `next` member, `s = &(*s)->next` - and loop to check the conditions again.
  - If the condition is `false` it means that `newNode` should be inserted between the node to which the `next` member `s` points at belongs and the `*s` node - and the loop terminates. When the loop terminates `s` will therefore point at a `next` member where the new node should be inserted.

It can be hard to "see" it without actually doing this with pen and paper so I recommend doing just that. Insert 3 nodes using only pen and paper and draw the pointers to see where everything ends up. It usually gives me an "aha!" moment.

Comment: Thank you this solves my problem, however, the demo code does not run on the command prompt for some reason....there are no errors but it doesn't print the output.

Comment: @on_my_puter You're welcome! In the demo I commented out `fp = fopen("employee.txt", "r");`  and replaced it with `fp = stdin;` - so, just do the opposite. Comment out `fp = stdin;` and uncomment the `fopen` line.

Comment: If its alright could please explainwhat happens in this code please:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         'while (*s && strcmp(newNode->personalInfo.name, (*s)->personalInfo.name) > 0) 
{
  s = &(*s)->next;
 }
 // `s` now points at the `EmpTagPtr` pointer where the new node should be inserted:
  newNode->next = *s;
  *s = newNode;'

Comment: @on_my_puter Sure. I'm at a wedding party right now so I'll do it when things calm down :-)

Comment: Sure, take your time :)

Comment: @on_my_puter I added some explanations. I'll clarify it further if there are details you feel I left out. :-)

Comment: I did it on paper and I understood the linking and dereferencing part, Thank you so much for your help <3

Answer (score 1):

As Allan Wind already commented on your question, the first problem was that you had commas in `fscanf` even though your data is seperated by spaces.

A bigger problem is that segmentation fault occurs in the following while loop in your `insert()` function

```c
while(current != NULL && strcmp(current->personalInfo.name , prev->personalInfo.name) >0 )
{
    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
}
```

This happens because you are accesing `personalInfo` of `prev` when `prev` is set to `NULL`. I assume that what you wanted to do here is insert an elemente into the linked list so that the list stays sorted alphabetically by names. In that case, you must compare names of `current` and `newNode` in `strcmp` and NOT names of `current` and `prev`. Your condition in the while loop should look like this:

```c
while(current != NULL && prev != NULL && strcmp(current->personalInfo.name , newNode->personalInfo.name) > 0 )
```

Comment: I just realized that the point of insert is probably to insert it in alphabetical order. Could you confirm if that is the case? I'm editing the answer to fix it

Comment: Yes, I want to print the list in alphabetical order. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm sorry, not printing, I want to insert in alphabetical order.

Comment: cool, I already edited my answer so that it is sorted after insertion, but is currently in reverse alphabetical order. To sort alphabetically you can change `strcmp(...) > 0` to `strcmp(...) < 0`

Answer (score 1):

I think an important point to improve your programme is [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You might end up with roughly:

[image: Normalized.]

Where, `person.txt` is (an example),

```
1 Peter 30
2 Joseph 50
3 Mary 40
```

`works.txt`

```
1 1001 8000
2 1002 4000
3 1002 6000
```

`department.txt`

```
1001 1
1002 1
```

`company.txt`

```
1 Apple
```

Instead of duplicating data, this reduces data redundancy. This is good for if you want to add or make changes to your database. It also mirrors the usage (somewhat) in your programme.